# Stop JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog from showing 2 times?

Tags: java

**Please read till the end, I have 3 questions 
Here's my code:**

```
public class oncancel implements ActionListener {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    int confirm=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "exit window ?",
      "msgbox",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

     if(confirm==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ 
        new graphic();
     }     //returns to the main frame

  }
}
```

1) this code appears 2 times BUT it should only appear once ??

2) this code opens a new window when i choose yes BUT what if I want to stay in the same window like "back to the main page" ??

3) this code is in "x1" class on "cancel" button. If yes is clicked it should return to "x" class

is there something like

```
{
  new graphic().x();
} ??
```

### thanks for your time :))

```
public class graphic { 
...
xbutton.addActionListener(new x()); -->this one's in graphic
...
}

private class x implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       ...
       x1button.addActionListener(new x1());
       ....
}}

public class x1 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
     ...
     cancel.addActionListener(new oncancel());
     ...
}}

public class oncancel implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int confirm=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "exit window?", "msg box", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(confirm==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
            new graphic();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide the complete code. Meaning how you are registering action listener to button? What is graphic ? What is X1 and X?

Comment: graphic() is the main window

Comment: what is the statement 'new graphic();' intended to do? You say it means return to main frame but generally a constructor would not be used to change focus or close a window. This would be quite unusual. I am asking because there is a chance that is what is causing the dialog to appear a second time.

Comment: On question 2 do you mean 'what if you want one of the options in the confirmation dialog to leave the dialog open?' If so then you will need to create your own dialog for this: the JOptionPane utility methods are intended to be modal. That is they pop up a message and then wait until the user dismisses them.

Comment: check the code plz I edited it,
the JOptionPane opens a new window with the content of "graphic class" but I want it to go back to "x1" with its content :\

Comment: what should I add to the code to make it appear only once ??